# Unable to use WiFi after/during using thunderbolt ethernet adapter

Tags: wifi, thunderbolt, ethernet

when I use my thunderbolt ethernet adapter I'm not able to connect to the WiFi, either when the adapter is plugged or not.

I tried to check for errors in `/var/logs/wifi` and I got this:

```
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.667 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.667 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 8e:15:54:a8:85:1b
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.667 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 3 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.667 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 98:01:a7:97:85:83
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.667 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 113)
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 1 of 4
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 <kernel> FULL RSN IE FOUND:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 [00000000] 30 18 01 00 00 0F AC 02 02 00 00 0F AC 04 00 0F AC 02 01 00 00 0F AC 02 00 00
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.859 <kernel> storeFullRSNIE: getAP_IE_LIST returned 0
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 <kernel> PMK:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [00000000] 1F F0 55 0E D3 C9 A7 B0 FC 95 80 09 E5 51 C3 9C F8 4F D9 96 8F A7 43 A6 F0 40 88 98 8D 7D
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [0000001E] 41 63
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 <kernel> TPTK:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [00000000] 70 0D 15 AD 35 98 6F 10 1C 7C D4 89 93 AF 79 F8 38 66 C2 28 B3 FF BD 99 C1 53 73 B7 5B E2
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [0000001E] 6D 51 F2 E5 31 5B 65 D1 48 D3 29 C2 44 CA B7 E2 EC FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [0000003C] 00 00 00 00
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 <kernel> KEY MIC:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 [00000000] 0A 96 4D 8E 0E D8 F2 02 60 7D 9F 2A FF 67 29 3A
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.860 <kernel> process1of4: sending replyPacket 135 bytes
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.890 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 217)
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.893 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.893 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: decrypting key data
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.895 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 3 of 4
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.895 <kernel> process3of4: Performing IE check.
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.896 <kernel> process3of4: sending replyPacket ( len = 113 ).
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.896 <kernel> process3of4: received pairwise GTK
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.897 <kernel> ptkThread: Sleeping!
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.897 <kernel> ptkThread: Installing PTK!
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.897 <kernel> PTK:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.897 [00000000] F2 E5 31 5B 65 D1 48 D3 29 C2 44 CA B7 E2 EC FF
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.898 <kernel> ptkThread: Installing GTK!
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.899 <kernel> installGTK: setting cipher key (flags = 0x0)
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.909 <kernel> GTK-RSC:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.909 [00000000] 00 00 00 00 00 00
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.909 <kernel> GTK:
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.918 [00000000] 46 EF EF CA 46 7B AC 4E 41 B4 C8 24 74 5D 94 2C 6A 72 C4 30 78 A9 DB 22 67 50 1B 1E 69 2C
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.920 [0000001E] 2D DA
Wed Apr 26 16:43:34.920 <kernel> installGTK: GTK installed
Wed Apr 26 16:43:35.024 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Wed Apr 26 16:43:35.126 <kernel> en0: link down event, informing supplicant.
Wed Apr 26 16:43:35.126 <kernel> AirPort_Brcm4360::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: 6
```

I tried to google for `APPLE80211_IOC_SSID` without any luck. 
Not sure what else to check

EDIT: Hardware information

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro12,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2,7 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory:   8 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP121.0167.B24
  SMC Version (system): 2.28f7
  Serial Number (system):   C02RT9G7FVH3
  Hardware UUID:    CA187980-F2EC-55D0-BB34-90A3DE6B3FE2


Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter:

  Vendor Name:  Apple Inc.
  Device Name:  Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
  Vendor ID:    0x1
  Device ID:    0x8003
  Device Revision:  0x1
  UID:  0x000100020637BE70
  Apple Serial Number:  DTN630604LHDWKHB8
  Route String: 1
  Firmware Version: 5,5
  Port (Upstream):
  Status:   Device connected
  Link Status:  0x2
  Speed:    Up to 10 Gb/s x1
  Port Micro Firmware Version:  0.0.8
```

Comment: Please let us know your machine's specs: macOS version, machine model and year, model of your Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @Allan done! sorry :)

Comment: When you say _I'm not able to connect to the WiFi_ can you clarify what actually happens? For example, are you able to turn Wi-Fi off and on again, or is it totally greyed out/unresponsive? Does it look like it's trying to connect to Wi-Fi or not? Or, do you mean it actually _does_ connect to Wi-Fi, but that it's not getting an internet connection? Also, what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Can you confirm/clarify when you say you can't *connect to the WiFi, either when the adapter is plugged or not?*  Are you unplugging Ethernet from the adapter, or the adapter from the MBP?  Can you provide a scenario where WiFi actually works?

Comment: I had internet sharing enabled, so when I plugged the adapter the wifi would disconnect and start sharing the connection. After that moment when I tried to connect to any other wifi it work work. I tried removing the adapter but it was still not working. I had to restart my laptop to make it work. I have disabled internet sharing and it seems to work. Will let you know if I still get the issue.